# SDHC Card causes windows explorer to freeze

Tags: freeze, crash, file-transfer, sd-card

I have a 4GB SDHC card with some photos that I would like to download from it, I can connect it to my computer and browse through the folders, but when I try to move any of the images or videos to another folder, or off of the SD Card, windows explorer freezes. If I try to scan for errors, it fails.

If I try to see it through a USB Card reader, windows explorer crashes.

If I try to download the photos onto a chromebook, the card does not show up (though that might be the specific card reader).

If I connect it to a camera, and connect the camera to the computer, windows explorer fails.

I even tried to connect it to a raspberry pi, but after successfully mounting the card to the filesystem, and descending into the folders, using CP to copy the files to my user folder, cp freezes.

Why the heck could this be happening, every other card I use works perfectly find.

Comment: How do you know it's freezing, and not just trying to read slowly? Are there any messages in system logs (on a raspberry pi or linux, maybe chromebook too, something should show up in `dmesg` or `/var/log/syslog` or something in `/var/log/`). Tried copying the whole device to a file with `dd`, then mount & read the image?

Comment: @Xen2050 it's definitely freezing. Windows explorer ends up getting the "this program is not responding" dialog, and has to be restarted (sometimes it crashes and restarts on its own). Using dd is a good idea though, it will look into that, but based on the past tests, I doubt it will work, therefore I still, would like to see more ideas.

Comment: Try a different card reader too, maybe it's the problem. If you can't read a drive, and it freezes & doesn't respond at all, it's probably broken, replace it. A 4GB card's probably under $5 if you can still find any. Worst case could be it's trying to infect your Windows, but that shouldn't affect linux / raspberryPi much. (A well designed program shouldn't crash just because a disk isn't responding fast enough, but I remember way way back that Windows Explorer did enjoy crashing at the drop of a hat, or a cool breeze...)

Comment: @Xen2050 I know its not the card reader, as it happens with a couple of readers, and other cards work find on the reader. I have not go around to trying dd yet, after that I am getting ready to find someone with a NAND reader and taking the nuclear option.

Comment: Unless it's for data recovery, I'd keep in mind the replacement cost of a 4GB sd card, compared to the time/cost in "repairing" it. Though there's also an educational/fun benefit too...

Comment: If the SD card is not destroyed/corrupt, just ejecting it always unfreezes the frozen processes/threads. Then you can re-insert it. In the case of damaged or corrupt cards the eject part will probably still work but putting it back in will generally result in another freeze. Incompatible card readers can do this too, typically when your card has a newer standard than the reader was designed for.